# Using a maven library that's not in a repository

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I have a library (JBPT) that's built using maven, but it's not in any repository.

I've downloaded the library's source code, extracted it and ran "mvn install clean" in its root folder as instructed by the library author. I can see the library is now built and installed under my ~/.m2 directory.

Now I want to add the library as a dependency to my project. The artifact for JBPT in their pom.xml is declared as:

```
<groupId>org.jbpt</groupId>
<artifactId>jbpt</artifactId>
<version>0.2.393</version>
```

Now, in my project I've added it as a dependency to my pom.xml like so:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jbpt</groupId>
  <artifactId>jbpt</artifactId>
  <version>0.2.393</version>
</dependency>
```

Despite the library being there in my ~/.m2 local repository, when compiling my project it's not able to get the dependency, it fails with the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project modelvsdocument: Could not
resolve dependencies for project <MY PROJECT>: Failure to find 
org.jbpt:jbpt:jar:0.2.393 in <SOME REPOSITORY I'M USING> was cached in 
the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the 
update interval of <THE NAME OF THE REPOSITORY> has elapsed or updates 
are forced -> [Help 1]
```

I don't understand why it's trying to get the repository information from an outside repository it hasn't come from.

Why is this failing and how may I fix it?

Comment: What happens when you use the _offline_ option (mvn -o clean install) ?

Comment: @Linuslabo Nothing changes apparently

Comment: Propably in that pom there is a <distributionManagement> tag, pointing to external repositories.

Comment: No, I've checked and that's not the case. It seems that the library consists on many sub-libraries (declared as modules on the main pom.xml) though. I don't know if that might be relevant in this case.

Comment: Have you tried to build with `mvn clean install -U`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue with JBPT is that you need to depend on the relevant submodules e.g. jbpt-core in your pom file, not on the packaging uber pom.